# Subheader overflow in Help Center Reputation & Moderation section

Tags: bug, design, help-center

When viewing a topic in the [Reputation & Moderation section of the Help Center](//meta.stackexchange.com/help/reputation), e.g. [What is reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), the sub header text is split into two lines, pushing the topic header to the right:

> [image]

Can this please be fixed?

Chrome 52 under Windows 7 here.

Comment: Yeah, reported already on MSO. An update to Chrome seems to have caused it. No idea if it is Chrome or us (this happens on some site designs and not on others).

Comment: Thanks, since it affects all sites, it belongs here.

Comment: Amusingly, Chrome Canary (54, the dev version) *doesn't* have this bug.

Comment: @ArtOfCode heh, so maybe browser bug indeed.